# Sounds no longer playing after importing project to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sammet-1yms2?file=/public/index.html
This is my minimal reproducible example.

When the page was only static html with javascript the sounds were working.  After refactoring into a React app the sounds have stopped working and I get 2 errors: `Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.` and `(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`

When I paste the HTML file path into the browser the sounds are working, but when I run the app on localhost there are errors and no sounds.  The rest of the javascript is working, and I have made sure the file path for the sounds is correct.

[This is my directory layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWFU3.png)

This code is from daily-planner/public/planner.js and shows the audio play functions:

```
var penNoises = ["../src/sounds/Pen1.wav", "../src/sounds/Pen2.wav"];
var randomPen = Math.floor(Math.random() * penNoises.length);

function penSound() {
  var audio = new Audio(
    penNoises[Math.floor(Math.random() * penNoises.length)]
  );
  audio.volume = 0.1;
  audio.play();
}

function penCross() {
  var audio = new Audio("../src/sounds/penCross1.wav");
  audio.play();
  }
```

The event listeners that call these functions are attached to `<li>`'s that are dynamically generated from an array, not `<audio>` elements.

Comment: May be a similar issue as when trying to use images in react components. Try importing the sound assets and referencing the imported object in the component instead, or in-line `require` them. If you can update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and possibly a *running* codesandbox to debug in) there may be a higher chance of helping resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Actually, the sounds and the elements they are attached to are completely separate from the react component.  There is only one React component so far.  I will attempt to update the question, but I don't as of yet know how to create a sandbox using react and vanilla javascript in separate files.

Comment: If you are familiar with vscode then [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is a nearly identical clone, with react and vanilla-js templates to get started. If you are familiar with any other recent IDEs it should still be fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.  I was able to use codesandbox easily.  Unfortunately the code snippet tool is outdated as far as react is concerned, and doesn't allow you to upload outside media. Updating now with codesandbox linked.

Comment: @PsiKai I believe you can't access a file on src from a file on public, that's what causes trouble. If you move the **sound** to `public` and then modify the path, it works fine.  [codesandbox for a quick test](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-pasteur-oudp3?file=/public/planner.js). BTW [repl.it](https://repl.it) is light years better IMHO

Comment: Doesn't seem an easy problem. but you have [part of the whys here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is the way React compiles the files.

1. All that is on the src folder, is packed up in a folder named 'static'.
2. And every file in there is properly linked to the index.html file.
   (and I mean, linked as we would expect from the un-compiled project).
3. It is recommended to load assets on src.

But *links on the public folder remain intact*, they do not follow the re-arrangment in directories done by the compilation. Run `npm run build` or `npm start` to check out.

- So the path on your planner.js contains a URL - that's expected - but is pointing nowhere.

---

That being said/sad, what is logic in the raw project, may not be what is compiled. To be better off maybe [look at these rules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

Basically, planner and .wav would be better placed in the source folder. You can also move the .wav file in the public folder (not best option).

I've [fixed your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-pasteur-oudp3?file=/public/planner.js) with that second approach. In part, because it's not easy to deduce from the post if you really need that `planner.js` in public or not.

Anyways, Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know if you've not saved your update/fix, but OP's issue still repros in your sandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese oh thanks. no i've been playing with the code after the post (and the comment). Done

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the audio file inside of the public folder since the script using it is inside public.

[image]

```
function playSound() {
  var audio = new Audio("./penCross1.wav");
  audio.play();
}
```

[image: Edit blazing-lake-oezh3]

---

Alternatively, you can put `planner.js` inside `src` so you can access the wav file residing inside `src`